# Shiny: Show action buttons only when certain input is selected

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app with multiple tabs. On one of the tabs, I have an option between `base 1` and `base 2`. Choosing `base 1` leads to a checkboxgroup with many different options while `base 2` leads to a simple selectInput where can you choose one of only two options.

When choosing `base 1` I have added `select all` and `deselect all` buttons (in the form of action links). I would like to show these buttons only when `base 1` is selected. My first instinct was to put the two action links into the same `renderUI` as the checkboxgroup, but then the `observe` function to update the checkboxgroup input did not recognize the action link IDs and crashed.

So I thought maybe I can simply hide them when they are not needed using `shinyjs`, but this does not seem to work either. Below is my sample code (I have chosen to include two tabs, since all answers I could find online did not work for me and consisted of problems with only one tab present).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
```

UI:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "First Past Yield"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("stats",lib = "glyphicon")),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("dashboard",lib = "glyphicon"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 4,
                       box(title = "Inputs",width = NULL,status = 'primary',solidHeader = TRUE,
                           checkboxGroupInput("some_input",h3("Some Input"),choices = list("Input 1" = 1,"Input 2" = 2,"Input 3" = 3),
                                             selected = c(1,2),inline = TRUE))),
                column(width = 8,
                       box(title = "Outputs",width = NULL,status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, "Some Output")))),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 4,
                       box(title = "Inputs",width = NULL,status = 'primary',solidHeader = TRUE,
                           selectInput("base",h3("Basis"),choices = list("Base 1" = 1,"Base 2" = 2),selected = 1),
                           uiOutput("basestuff"),
                           actionLink("selectall","Select All"),
                           actionLink("selectnone",HTML(paste('&emsp;',"Deselect All")))
                       )),
                column(width = 8,
                       box(title = "Outputs",width = NULL,status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, "Some Output")))))))
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  output$basestuff <- renderUI({
    if(input$base == 1){
      checkboxGroupInput("many_choices",h3("Many Choices"),choices = list("a" = 1,"b" = 2,"c" = 3,"d" = 4,"e" = 5, "f" = 6, "g" = 7),
                         selected = 1:7,inline = TRUE)
    }
    else if(input$base == 2){
      selectInput("few_choices",h3("Few Choices"),choices = list("a" = 1,"b" = 2),selected = 1)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "selectall",condition = input$base == 1)
  })
  
  observe({
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "selectnone",condition = input$base == 1)
  })
  
  observe({
    if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL)
    else if (input$selectall > 0){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"many_choices",choices = list("a" = 1,"b" = 2,"c" = 3,"d" = 4,"e" = 5, "f" = 6, "g" = 7),
                               selected = 1:7,inline = TRUE)}
  })
  
  observe({
    if(input$selectnone == 0) return(NULL)
    else if (input$selectnone > 0){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"many_choices",choices = list("a" = 1,"b" = 2,"c" = 3,"d" = 4,"e" = 5, "f" = 6, "g" = 7),inline = TRUE)
    }
  })
}
```

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this instead of the two toggles: and dont forget to put `useShinyjs(),` into the `dashboardBody`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "First Past Yield"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("stats",lib = "glyphicon")),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("dashboard",lib = "glyphicon"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 4,
                       box(title = "Inputs",width = NULL,status = 'primary',solidHeader = TRUE,
                           checkboxGroupInput("some_input",h3("Some Input"),choices = list("Input 1" = 1,"Input 2" = 2,"Input 3" = 3),
                                              selected = c(1,2),inline = TRUE))),
                column(width = 8,
                       box(title = "Outputs",width = NULL,status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, "Some Output")))),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab2",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 4,
                       box(title = "Inputs",width = NULL,status = 'primary',solidHeader = TRUE,
                           selectInput("base",h3("Basis"),choices = list("Base 1" = 1,"Base 2" = 2),selected = 1),
                           uiOutput("basestuff"),
                           actionLink("selectall","Select All"),
                           actionLink("selectnone",HTML(paste('&emsp;',"Deselect All")))
                       )),
                column(width = 8,
                       box(title = "Outputs",width = NULL,status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, "Some Output")))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$basestuff <- renderUI({
    if(input$base == 1){
      checkboxGroupInput("many_choices",h3("Many Choices"),choices = list("a" = 1,"b" = 2,"c" = 3,"d" = 4,"e" = 5, "f" = 6, "g" = 7),
                         selected = 1:7,inline = TRUE)
    }
    else if(input$base == 2){
      selectInput("few_choices",h3("Few Choices"),choices = list("a" = 1,"b" = 2),selected = 1)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$base,{
    if(input$base == 1){
      shinyjs::show("selectall")
      shinyjs::show("selectnone")
    }else{
      shinyjs::hide("selectall")
      shinyjs::hide("selectnone")
    }
  })
  
  
  observe({
    if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL)
    else if (input$selectall > 0){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"many_choices",choices = list("a" = 1,"b" = 2,"c" = 3,"d" = 4,"e" = 5, "f" = 6, "g" = 7),
                               selected = 1:7,inline = TRUE)}
  })
  
  observe({
    if(input$selectnone == 0) return(NULL)
    else if (input$selectnone > 0){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"many_choices",choices = list("a" = 1,"b" = 2,"c" = 3,"d" = 4,"e" = 5, "f" = 6, "g" = 7),inline = TRUE)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yep, this works also in my actual app. I had `useShinyjs()` in some iteration somewhere, but I guess at the wrong place since it threw an error. Thanks a lot and have a great weekend!